# Netty doc bug for ServerBootstrap.group()?

Tags: netty

The netty javadoc for `ServerBootstrap.group()` method is this:

[image]

I think the `SocketChannel` should be `ServerChannel`.

I am using `Netty 4.0.24.Final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right... please open a PR with a fix:
https://github.com/netty/netty/pulls

Comment: Thanks Mr. Norman Maurer. I am reading your book < Netty In Action > v10. It's a great book.  (It's much better than v5. ^_^)  May I ask if there'll be any update for the latest netty 5.0?